# Transform a Model3DGroup twice

Tags: c#, wpf

I need to transform a Model3DGroup twice (once to set the position, and once to set the rotation). I tried this:

```
var model = ModelImporter.Load(gameAssetPath);
model.Transform = new TranslateTransform3D(
        placedObject.SpawnCoordinates.X,
        placedObject.SpawnCoordinates.Y,
        placedObject.SpawnCoordinates.Z);
var modelRotation = new Model3DGroup();
modelRotation.Children.Add(model);
modelRotation.Transform = new RotateTransform3D(new AxisAngleRotation3D(), placedObject.SpawnCoordinates.Roll, placedObject.SpawnCoordinates.Pitch, placedObject.SpawnCoordinates.Yaw);
```

And that was a no-go. I've searched on google and SO, and can't seem to find anything.

Comment: What exactly goes wrong? It depends on what you what to achieve but applying the rotation before the translation will more than likely give you what you want.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need [TransformGroup](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.transformgroup.aspx) class for this.

That class will combine your transforms.

```
var model = ModelImporter.Load(gameAssetPath);
var modelRotation = new Model3DGroup();
modelRotation.Children.Add(model);
var t1 = new TranslateTransform3D(
        placedObject.SpawnCoordinates.X,
        placedObject.SpawnCoordinates.Y,
        placedObject.SpawnCoordinates.Z);
var t2 = new RotateTransform3D(
         new AxisAngleRotation3D(), 
        placedObject.SpawnCoordinates.Roll, 
        placedObject.SpawnCoordinates.Pitch, 
        placedObject.SpawnCoordinates.Yaw);
var tg = new TransformGroup();
tg.Children.Add(t1);
tg.Children.Add(t2);
modelRotation.Transform = tg;
```

Comment: Link only answers aren't good answers. It would be better to summarise the page here (and use the actual link rather than the Google link)

Comment: It's fine, the link gave me all I needed :).

Comment: @AlexReed - that may be true *now*, but if the page linked to disappears then the answer becomes useless.

Comment: Turns out I needed `Transform3DGroup`, but thanks for pointing me in the right direction. I'll mark this as the answer as soon as SO lets me.